# Function pointer confusion: Making a function dispatcher in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, type-alias

I have a function that acts as a "function dispatch." This function contains a variable named `next_func`, which is initialized to the first function to load. Then, inside an infinite loop, the `next_func` is set to the return value of itself.

My question is, besides using `auto`, what type does `next_func` need to be? Here's some **conceptual** code (using `auto`) to give an idea of what I'm looking for:

```cpp
void FunctionDispatch()
{
    auto next_menu = first_menu;
    while (next_menu != app_exit)
    {
        next_menu = next_menu();
    }
}

auto first_menu()
{
    auto return_menu = first_menu; // Set to itself for 'auto', but I don't want to have to do this

    std::cout << "2 or 3? ";
    unsigned input = 0;
    std::cin >> input;

    switch (input)
    {
    case 2:
        return_menu = second_menu;
        break;

    case 3:
        return_menu = third_menu;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return return_menu;
}
```

I like using `auto` for trivial types, but I don't really like relying on it because I don't know how to address the type I'm wanting, which is why I'm wondering what `auto` actually is here and how to explicitly declare the variables and function return types (probably using type aliases since that's most sensible).

Something to note:

- All functions that `FunctionDispath()` can call take no parameters and return function pointers to other functions that take in no parameters and return the same type of function pointers.
- I'd prefer an answer that explains both what the full type would be with no type aliases *and* how to use a type alias here.

Comment: @walnut This situation exists to prevent a lot of nested calls. I could call `third_menu` from `second_menu` from `first_menu` and so on, but that will result in a stack overflow when I have something like `hundredth_menu`. By using a dispatch system, I'm attempting to let every function exit back to the `FunctionDispatch` function, thus reducing the call stack. I cannot provide a reproducible example because I don't know how to do what I want to do (hence why I posted it). I also understand the type cannot be deduced, which is why I want to know how to specify it explictly.

Comment: I misunderstood you. I thought you were already using code similar to the posted one and were looking to figure the deduced types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, cool! This reminds me of middleware frameworks, or coroutines with tasks and event loops.

Doing this with straight-up function pointers will result in an infinitely recursive type, as many have mentioned. But if each task is a callable object, then you don't need recursive types as a forward reference will do. You can inherit `std::function` to make it easy:

```cpp
struct task : std::function<task()> {
    using std::function<task()>::function;
};
```

Then you can assign functions to it. You can also bind arguments with `std::bind`, or even use the default constructor to make an empty function with no target:

```cpp
task n_hellos(int count) {
    if (count) {
        std::cout << "hello\n";
        return std::bind(n_hellos, count-1);
    }
    return task();
}
```

You can cast an `std::function` to bool to see if it is empty, allowing for a terminal case. The event loop below quits when the next task is empty:

```cpp
int main() {
    task current_task = std::bind(n_hellos, 5);
    while (current_task) {
        current_task = current_task();
    }
} // prints "hello" five times
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/dHaSWC